# How to memoize a class method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a class method which is heavy in computation that I call many times per request.

Ideally i'd like to cache the result for the duration of a single request.

What's rails best practice in this situation?

Example:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.heavy_method; ... ; end
end
```

Then in a helper

```
def helper
  MyClass.heavy_method
end
```

This helper is used in many views

Comment: What type of class? In other words, where does it live? Is it reasonable for it to be a class method (as opposed to instance)? How is it called; is it across multiple objects?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a very generic solution that might work for you.

```
class Klass
  def self.memoized_expensive_method
    @memoized_expensive_method_result ||= expensive_method
  end

  def self.expensive_method
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then if you want to ensure your code is re-executed on every request, you could use a filter in your controller.

```
class Klass
  def self.reset_expensive_method_cache!
    @memoized_expensive_method_result = nil
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  before_filter :reset_klass_expensive_method_cache

  def reset_klass_expensive_method_cache
    Klass.reset_expensive_method_cache!
  end
end
```

Note that storing stuff in class variable might lead to thread-safety issue because the cached result will be shared between threads.

If this can be an issue for your application you might want to store the data in the thread instead of using a class variable.

Comment: Great answer. A more fool-proof reset would address all class instance variables, though. `self.instance_variables.each { |v| instance_variable_set(v, nil) }`

Comment: It's worth noting that you likely will use a web server with multiple threads. Two requests at the same time on different threads will race & compete for the cache. It is inadvisable to use this solution to cache per-request. The [RequestStore](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem is thread-safe

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @unixcharles, here's what i ended doing

```
class SomeClass
  @lock = Mutex.new

  after_save :clear_cached_calculation

  class << self
    def some_calculation
      @lock.synchronize do
        @calc ||= heavy_operation
      end
    end

    def clear_calculation
      @lock.synchronize do
        @calc = nil
      end
    end

  end

private

  def clear_cached_caculation
    SomeClass.clear_calculation
  end
end
```

Edit:

It's probably a better solution to use `Rails.cache.fetch` instead of keeping the value in memory.